# nHibernate Envers Get history record for deleted revision

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I store entity changes in database using Envers. I configured StoreDataAtDelete parameters to true and is works fine. Database contains history data.

However, when I try to query audit data to get historical record state for deleted revision, I get an empty result.

```
_session.Auditer().CreateQuery()
    .ForEntitiesAtRevision<TEntity>(revisionId)
    .Add(AuditEntity.Id().Eq(recordId))
    .Results();
```

In database, for this revision there is full record data in audit table. Is there any possibility to get data for deleted revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just an overload that is missing.

Does it work if you use

```
ForEntitiesAtRevision("TEntity", revisionId, true)
```

instead?

Report it to the [Jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/projects/NHE) if you want to.

Comment: There is no `ForEntities` method. Instead I use `_session.Auditer().Find(typeof(TEntity).FullName, recordId, revisionId, true);` and it works

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Yes, find method works if you don't need more filters than revisionid.